# Bootstrap not being applied to a dynamically loaded table in datatables

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

So I'm trying to run allow anyone to run a query on my db and then I'd like to display the result on the page. Since the query can return any number of columns I'm calculating the number of columns after the query has returned and then creating the table. The issue is that I've tried using Bootstrap styling as provided in Datatables docs but although the page buttons are correctly styled the table isn't.

The html which comes with the page is styled correctly and the classes which are generated seem to correspond with the ones in Bootstrap docs but still style isn't applied.

You can check out the page on www.dito.ninja for complete code.

```
extends layout

block head
    link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css")

    script(type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")
    script(type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js")
    script(type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js")
    script(type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8")

block content
  .row
    .col-lg-6
      div.label.label-default Table name is 'products'. Write queries like "SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 100;"
  .row
    .col-lg-6
      .input-group(role = "group")
        input.form-control#my-input(type='text' value ='SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 100;' style="width: 500px;")
        span.input-group-btn
          button.btn.btn-default#my-button(type='button' onclick='buttonclicked()') Work! Work!
  .row
    table#my-table

  script.
        function buttonclicked(){
            $.post( '/users/query/', {qq: $('#my-input').val()} , function( data ) {
                var cols = [];
                for (var col in data[0]) cols.push({"title": col});
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                    var newRow = [];
                    for (var val in data[i]) {
                        newRow.push(data[i][val]);
                    }
                    data[i] = newRow;
                }
                $('#my-table').dataTable({
                    "data": data,
                    "columns": cols
                });   
            });
        }
```

Comment: Aren't you forgetting the .table class?

Comment: Yeah, I thought it would get added with the script. The odd/even row coloring is still missing tho

Comment: add `class="table table-striped"` to your table, i.e `<table id="my-table" class="table table-striped dataTable no-footer">`  Then I does that in chrome dev tools your table looks OK. The bootstrap table classes does appear themselves by magic :)

Comment: Post is as an answer if you'd like

Answer (score 0):

call your function with some timeout

```
setTimeout(function(){
  buttonclicked()
},1000);
```

possibly you would be calling it before loading the DOM/script